# How to align 4 subfloats of different size?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to control the image positioning that way that the space between the images is always a straight cross. But for unequal image width it doesn't work. I want to use `subfloat` and `textwidth` to. How can i solve this?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[!hbtp]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{1.png}}\quad%
\subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{1.png}}\\%
\subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{1.png}}\quad%
\subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{1.png}}%
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Addendum:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\subfloat[]{\label{fig-a}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
    &   \subfloat[]{\label{fig-b}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \\%
\subfloat[]{\label{fig-c}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
    &   \subfloat[]{\label{fig-d}\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Next time please provide complete document, not only code fragment.

**Addendum:**
From your comment I guess that you wish the following:

[image]

For this figure layout you need to ad package `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\subfloat[\label{fig-a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
    &   \subfloat[\label{fig-b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \\%
\subfloat[\label{fig-c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
    &   \subfloat[\label{fig-d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (2):**
According to addendum to your question, you probably like to arrange sub images as follows:

[image]

For this arrangement I add option `valign=T` also to images in the first row. `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\subfloat[\label{fig-a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
    &   \subfloat[\label{fig-b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
    \\%
\subfloat[\label{fig-c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
    &   \subfloat[\label{fig-d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For me the Figures are aligned at their top not at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. Do you like to have, that images are aligned with their top sides? Or you can't reproduce showed result? Please, elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, i mean c and d should be aligned at their top!

Comment: @jonastrautmann, see addendum to my answer. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: YeS1 yout solved it! Congratulation and thank you very much

Comment: @jonastrautmann, I'm just curious, why suddenly  my answer not solve your problem anymore? What had to be different in it?

Comment: @ Zarko, i have to come back to the Problem. The First solution you posted gives the result i posted in the addendum: not aligned at the bottom/caption like your image

Comment: I sow the image. For future, please make your question more clear. If you say, that images had to be vertically aligned at top, than you save a lot a time and receive right solution with first version of answer. See the second addendum to my answer (if now gives what you like to have).

Comment: I encountered a problem together with the hyperref package. When loading this package it messes the alignment. Do you know about this?

Comment: Lets go step by step. I persuaded, that I solved your basic problem stated in question in frame of given conditions (use of `subfloat`), problem with `\hyperref`is different story. I suggest you to close this question as solved and ask new one, where you expose problem with `hypperref` (so more people, who can help you, will see your problem. In question please provide MWE (complete small document, which copy  can be compiled) which exhibit your problem and in title emphasize it with `hypperref`. It's known, than in some occasions arise issues with use of `hypperref` and `subfig` packages.