# Subfloat alignment problem with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, subfloats

Why does simply loading the hyperref package mess up the alignment and how can I solve this?

**Correct image and sample code:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,singlelinecheck=0,labelfont=bf]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X
                         >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\subfloat[]{\label{fig-a}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{1.png}}
&   \subfloat[]{\label{fig-b}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]    {1.png}}
\\%
\subfloat[]{\label{fig-c}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{1.png}}
&   \subfloat[]{\label{fig-d}\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{1.png}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Misalignment due to hyperref:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `\hyperref` forces alignment of  cell content according to its own standards. In the case of `tabular`, this means cell content will be top aligned. This doesn't matter, when the images included by `\includegraphics{...}` have the same height...

In your case, however, the images have different heights. If you prefer them to be bottom aligned, then the simplest cure is to redefine the `X` column:

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
```

which will result in:

[image]

The complete code for getting the MWE as above is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}

\usepackage[margin=0pt,singlelinecheck=0,labelfont=bf]{subfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\subfloat[\label{fig-a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
&   \subfloat[\label{fig-b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]    {example-image}}
\\%
\subfloat[\label{fig-c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}
&   \subfloat[\label{fig-d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If, however, you'd like to have the bottom images aligned at the top, but keep the top images aligned at the bottom (see Addendum 2 in my answer to your [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320549/how-to-align-4-subfloats-of-different-size)) you can employ the package `\adjustwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,singlelinecheck=0,labelfont=bf]{subfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\subfloat[\label{fig-a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
&   \subfloat[\label{fig-b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]    {example-image}}
\\%
\subfloat[\label{fig-c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
&   \subfloat[\label{fig-d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}%
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

in order to get:

[image]